# 画像を画面中央に持っていきたい。テキストテンプレートに文字を記入したい。

Tags: html, css

[image: 画面中央に固定したいです。Mac用及びモバイル用]

---

HTML ソースコード

```
<body>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div id="spdayo">
<a href="index.html"><img src="sp1.jpg" alt="ginzagakubuchi" width="589" height="585">
</a>
<div id="coolsright">
<a href="index.html"><img src="givemecoolsright.jpg" alt="Denencho-fu,田園調布2014" width="450" height="460">
</a></div>
</div>

<br/>
<div id="box">
<img src="template1.jpg" width="150" height="50">
<!--#boxtextを入力-->
<div id="boxtext">
<p>Welcome to Tokyo Hill </p>
</div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<!-- To Be Continued ...
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center>Copyrights(C) STANDAY 2017 </center>
-->

</body>
```

ーーーー
CSS

```
body {
  font-size: 28 px;
  font-family: Times New Roman, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}

#spdayo{
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#coolsright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 63px;
  left:68px;

}

#box {
  margin-left:　auto;
  margin-right:　auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 290px;
}

#boxtext{
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
}


@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px)
{
  #coolsright {
    position: absolute;
    top: 270px;
    left: 260px;
 }

 #spdayo{
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
 }
}
```

---

また、テキストプレートに影や、ボーダーラインを追記してエフェクトをあげたいです！
どのようにして書いたらベストかご教授ください！
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ```CSS
#box {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 52%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
```
こちらで解決しました。
youknow　WEB製作さん、ありがとうございました。

Comment: 自己解決した場合、自分の質問には自分で回答できます。[これは推奨されています](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)。是非お願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/69037

Answer (score 2):

```
#spdayo{
position: absolute;
top: 25%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

で解決できました、ありがとうございました！

Comment: 「解決しました」と書かれたコメントのCSSと異なりますが、こちらが正しいのでしょうか？またタイトルに書かれた2つの問題のうち、「画像を画面中央に持っていきたい」の方しか解決していないように見えるのですが・・・。

Comment: ありがとうございました。boxをdivとして、その中にboxtextを記入する形を取り, CSSでポジションを調整しました、 position: absolute; 。